# jquery delay won't work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a delay in a jQuery sequence but is refuses to work.

```
var old = $('.likes' + id).text();
$('.likes' + id).text("You've already voted").delay(3000).text(old);
```

Now, the old text gets entered right away with out the 'you've already voted' ever being displayed.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

As requested:

HTML:

```
<li>
                            <h2><a href="?page=dub&id=%%DUB_ID%%">%%DUB_TITLE%%</a></h2>
                            <div class="dub">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%%YOUTUBE_ID%%?hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                <div id="conten_wrapper">

                                    <div id="conten_meta">
                                        <p> Posted by: <a href="?page=profile&id=%%USER_ID%%">%%USERNAME%%</a><br />
                                            Likes: <span class="likes%%DUB_ID%%">%%LIKES%%</span><br />
                                            Date posted: %%DATE%%
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="conten_social">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:makeRequest(\'like\', %%DUB_ID%%)" class="likebtn">Like</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:makeRequest(\'dislike\', %%DUB_ID%%)" class="likebtn2">Dislike</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

js:

```
function makeRequest(name, id){
                $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "ajax.php",
                   data: "name=" + name + "&id=" + id,
                   success: function(msg){
                     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                     if(obj.status == "SUCCES"){
                        $('.likes' + id).html(parseInt($('.likes' + id).html(), 10)+1);
                     }else {
                        var old = $('.likes' + id).text();
                        $('.likes' + id).text("You've already voted").delay(3000).text(old);        
                     }
                   }
                 });
            }
```

Comment: Care to share your HTML?

Comment: delay() only works with jQuery's FX queue, which in other words means it only works on jQuery animations. To delay text insertion you'll have to use a timeout, like this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANw35/) ... On the other hand, you're doing it wrong, as the success callback will only fire if the ajax call is successful (suprise), and you probably need to use the error (fail) callback and not an if statement inside the success callback.

Comment: Something like this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANw35/1/) seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of doing this with setTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/ShYVR/

```
var vote = $('.likes' + id)
var text = vote.text();
setTimeout(function() { vote.text(text); }, 3000);
vote.text("You've already voted");​
```

Answer (score 4):

`delay` affects only jQuery's "queued effects" like `slideUp` and `fadeIn`, for other things you should use JavaScript's native `setTimeout`.

Comment: and how might i do this?

tried this:

$('.likes' + id).text("You've already voted").setTimeout(function() { $('.likes' + id).text(old) }, 3000);